# Why am I getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS after cast through int?

Tags: c, memory, pointers, exc-bad-access

In the code below I am getting an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error for no apparent reason when I call print vertex. The pointers point to the exact same location, but somehow it crashes when I pass in vp2.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} Vertex;

void printVertex(Vertex *v);

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Vertex v = {1,0,2};
    int memL = (int)&v;
    Vertex *vp = &v;

    printf("Memory Location: %i\n", memL);
    printf("Memory Pointed to by Pointer: %i\n", (int)vp);

    Vertex *vp2 = (Vertex *)memL;
    printf("Memory Pointed to by Pointer from memory location: %i\n", (int)vp2);

    printVertex(vp);  // Executes normally
    printVertex(vp2); // EXC_BAD_ACCESS

    return 0;
}

void printVertex(Vertex *v)
{
    printf("Vertex[%f,%f,%f]\n", v->x, v->y, v->z); // EXC_BAD_ACCESS when vp2 passed in
}
```

Output:

```
Memory Location: 1606416816
Memory Pointed to by Pointer: 1606416816
Memory Pointed to by Pointer from memory location: 1606416816
Vertex[1.000000,0.000000,2.000000]
EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error
```

Comment: It would be better to use `%p` to print pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int memL = (int)&v;
```

Might be truncating the adddress of `v`. You could try:

```
intptr_t memL = (intptr_t)&v;
```

to see if this is the case.  This should not crash if truncation is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your pointers are 64-bits wide, but your `int` type is only 32-bits wide.  You're throwing away half of the pointer information!

Comment: That should not make a difference because the as you can tell by the print statements, the location is the same so when I convert it back into a pointer, it would become 64 bits again.

Comment: No - you're only ever printing 32-bit numbers!  You're either printing an `int` or something casted to `int` in every case. Try printing one of those pointers without doing the crazy typecasting.  Something like:  `printf("%p\n", vp);`  You'll see what's up then.

Comment: I edited out the "probably" in my answer since it's not "probable", it's *exactly* what's happening.

Comment: Your print statements are doing the same truncation - use `%p` to print the pointer. That will reveal the truncation.